# How do I visualize geospatial data in a grid by using Python?

Tags: python, geospatial

I have two files: one of type .shp which is a grid and the other one of type .csv .In the .csv file there is a value refered to each cell of the grid in a certain time of the day. How can I visualize this information in Python such that higher values of data in cells of the grid will appear darker than those with lower values? I imagine I should join the data of the grid with those of the .csv file as both files have a common column which is cell_id.

I tried to use geopandas but not being very good at Python I had no success.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html     or http://geopandas.org/mapping.html

Comment: People here will (usually) not write all your code. So just put some code together and post it here if you have a specific problem (wrong display, error message,...)